# How can I fix this bug in my chess game where a move shows up on top of a piece?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was making a chess game, and all is well except that for example, a pawn, shows a move marker on a piece in front of it (pawns cant move like that). The game won't let you move there, since the move marker code is separate from the actual move code and check.

I have already tried many different approaches, such as iterating through every piece and checking if each piece is in front of the selected piece, as well as making sure that each piece iterated through is not the selected piece.

```
if (pieceSelected && !finishedPlacingMoveMarkers)
{
    if (selectedPiece.GetComponent<BlackPawn>())
    {
        if (selectedPiece.transform.position.y + 1 <= 3.5)
        {
            foreach (Transform child in pieces.transform)
            {
                if (child.tag == "Piece")
                {
                    if (obj.position == new Vector3(selectedPiece.transform.position.x, selectedPiece.transform.position.y + 1) && child.position != selectedPiece.transform.position)
                    {
                        if (child.position == new Vector3(selectedPiece.transform.position.x, selectedPiece.transform.position.y + 1))
                        {
                            noMoveHighlight = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            noMoveHighlight = false;
                        }  
                    }    
                }
            }

            if (!noMoveHighlight)
            {
                GameObject move1 = Instantiate(tileMoveHighlight);
                move1.transform.parent = moveTileHighlights.transform;
                move1.transform.position = new Vector3(selectedPiece.transform.position.x, selectedPiece.transform.position.y + 1, -0.9f);
            }      
        }

        finishedPlacingMoveMarkers = true;
    }
}
```

I expect the results to look like this when i select the pawn:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/iSA3mFi.png]

But they look like this:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/s25kb5E.png]

Please help!

Comment: There is a lot of repetition in this code. A new `Vector3` is created every loop and sometimes twice in the loop. Set it once then reference it. You can also collapse the nested `if` statements if nothing is happening inside the separate conditions.

Comment: i think this is a 2d game, you should be able to check if there is a 2d collider in front of a gameobject using 2d raycasting [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)

Comment: "The game won't let you move there, since the move marker code is separate from the actual move code and check." That is your issue rigth there. Of course there can be different layers of valdity. Some moves are invalid, because they would move the piece off the board. Some are invalid, because they move onto a allied piece. And even others are only valid if you move onto a enemy piece or your king out of mate. A chessgame is not a good learning case, due to the complexity of the rules.